# How to remove the first and the last item of a path components in Rust?

Tags: rust, vector

I would like to get the parts of the path and remove the first and the last part of it.

Example:

`a/b/c/d.txt` → `b/c`

I thought it could be done with simple list operation. However I could not find a nicer way:

```
let mut comps: Vec<_> = content_file.components().skip(1).collect();
comps.reverse();
let mut ret: Vec<_> = comps.iter().skip(1).collect();
ret.reverse();
```

Is there a nicer way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal favorite, the [`as_path` method of the `Components` iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Components.html#method.as_path), has no extra allocations, and does not need to redundantly compare the prefix or do other extra work:

```rust
let path = Path::new("a/b/c/d.txt");
let mut components = path.components();
components.next();      // remove the first component
components.next_back(); // remove the last component
let middle = components.as_path(); // ≙ Path::new("b/c")
```

Or you can write this oneliner which does an unnecessary allocation though:

```rust
let middle = PathBuf::from_iter(path.parent().unwrap().components().skip(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Path::parent`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html?search=pathbuf#method.parent) and [`Path::strip_prefix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html?search=pathbuf#method.strip_prefix) methods (see [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3da8651487548cdb6bcdea3d7af3c57)):

```rust
let parent = path.parent().expect("path has no parent");
let first_component = path.components().first().expect("path has no first component");
let final_path = parent.strip_prefix(first_component).unwrap();
```

With the input `a/b/c.txt`, this produces `b`.